# Mongodb:One to one chat schema

Tags: mongodb, database-schema

I am working on chat module,there will be a one to one chat in my application. I have to show recent message of both users like fb messenger or any app. So please suggest me how to make efficient schema to store chat conversation.

I am just thinking to have schema like

```
{
   owner:"prabh",
   messages:[{
    to:'john'
    sent:new Date(),
    messsage:"Hii"

}]
}
```

I am new to mongodb,any suggestions or improvements will be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: This query May come under primary Opinion Based ....

Answer (score 0):

Think simply, You can design Like this:

```
{
    "Id": " ",
    "userId": " ",
    "userName":" ",// who is sending the message
    "recepientId":" ",
    "recepient":" ",
    "sentTime":'' ",
    "receivedTime":" ",
    "msgBody": " ",
    "status": "" //seen or unseen

}
```